# Dependence of $C$ in $\|\Phi\|_{H^{1}}+\|z\|_{H^{1}}\leq C\|u\|_{H(\operatorname{curl})}$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory

I am stuck at the following exercise: Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. For $u \in H_{0}(\operatorname{curl},\Omega)$ there exists a decomposition $$u=\nabla \Phi +z$$ with $\Phi \in H_{0}^{1}$ and $z \in [H^{1}]^{2}$. Further $$\|\Phi\|_{H^{1}}+\|z\|_{H^{1}}\leq C\|u\|_{H(\operatorname{curl})}.$$

Up to this part I was successful, but I can't seem to be able to show the following second part:
Now consider $\Omega=(0,1)\times (0,a)$ with $a\leq1$. Show that the constsnt $C$ must depend on $a$, i.e. $C\geq \frac{c}{a^2}$ with a new constant $c$ independent of $a$.
The hint says to consider $$u(x,y):=(0,x(1-x))^{T}\in H_{0}(\operatorname{curl},\Omega).$$

My assumption is that the function in the hint should result in the inequality becoming an equality, but I wasn't able to work out the specific form of $\Phi$ in order to achieve the equality.

Edit:.$H_{0}(\operatorname{curl},\Omega):=\{ u\in [L^{2}]^2\: : \:\operatorname{curl}\in [L^{2}]^2, \operatorname{tr}(u)=u(x)\times n(x)=0\: \forall x\in\partial \Omega \}$, where $n$ denotes the outer normal and $\operatorname{tr}$ denotes the trace operator.

Comment: You're using notation that is not well-known and certainly isn't known to me. What is $H_0(\text{curl},\Omega)$?

Comment: Sorry, I will add the definition to the question.$H_{0}(\operatorname{curl},\Omega):=\{ u\in [L^{2}]^2\: : \:\operatorname{curl}\in [L^{2}]^2, \operatorname{tr}(u)=u(x)\times n(x)=0\: \forall x\in\partial \Omega \}$, where $n$ denotes the outer normal and $\operatorname{tr}$ denotes the trace operator. Regarding the notation, I tried to follow the standard PDE notation. (my problem is basically connected to the Maxwell equation)

Comment: In general the constant $C$ depends on the area $\Omega$ since the decomposition comes from the Lax-Milgram lemma (you define $\phi$ as the solution to $\int \nabla \phi \nabla v dx = \int f \nabla v dx$ for all $v\in $H^1_0(\Omega)$.